# Measuring magnetic fields in the 1-10 Hz range

Tags: frequency, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, frequency-measurement, field

I apologize in advance but I am a chemist just venturing into the world of electrical, so you may need to explain to me like a 5 year old.

I have a chemistry project that involves the use of AC magnetic fields at very low frequencies, 1 Hz to 10 Hz to be exact. The field strength will be varied between 10 and 25 mT.

I have been on the lookout for a gaussmeter I could use to measure field strengths at this low of a frequency range, but everything I have come across is 20-500 Hz or 40-500 Hz or the like, nothing as low as I need. Would it be better to use a probe hooked up to my oscilloscope? How would this be done?

Worst case, I can always monitor the current in my coils and simply calculate the field strength, but it would be good to have an quick and exact experimental value, measured at the exact point I need.

Comment: A hall sensor would be appropriate. It's sensitive down to DC and typically down to microtesla without any special voodoo.

Comment: One search term which may be helpful is "magnetometer" (combined with "chip", "module" etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Look around major electronics distributor websites for a Hall effect sensor *evaluation board*. It takes care of building a PCB around the sensor and interfacing it. You should be able to find one that plugs directly into a computer with USB and comes with rudimentary software as well as more detailed instructions for interfacing with it on the base level - I2C or whatever depending on the specific chip.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much any cheap magnetic sensor will do--most of them work down to DC. While there are some methods of magnetic sensing that can only detect time-varying fields, other common methods like the Hall effect and magnetoresistance can just as easily detect steady magnetic fields.

Just on a cursory search of digikey, I found the [Allegro A1304](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/allegro-microsystems/A1304ELHLX-T/4552948) and the [TI DRV5055](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/DRV5055A2QLPGM/8347156), both of which appear to meet your needs. And there's even the [TI DRV5053](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/DRV5053OAQDBZR/5015736) that can be powered by voltages as high as 36 V, if you need to interface with high-voltage industrial control systems.

You don't specify what kind of accuracy you need, however. It's entirely possible none of these actually will work, because none of them are particularly accurate--the DRV5053 in particular has a very wide spread of sensitivities.

The sensors I've specifically mentioned in this answer all output an analog voltage proportional to the sensed magnetic field along one axis (with an offset to allow representing both positive and negative fields without the output going negative). This makes them pretty easy to put on a stick that can be held in exactly the place you want to measure, and the analog output means you don't need any digital system to interpret their output--you can just hook it up to a sufficiently precise voltmeter. Analog output does, however, have the downside that noise can contaminate the signal more easily--if in a noisy environment, you may want to find an I²C or SPI interface sensor and hook it up to an arduino or something.

Comment: May I point out that there are many HALL sensors that have digital output rather than analog output...that is, they sense a magnetic field above or below a set-point threshold. These are not appropriate for the OP's application. Look only for **analog** magnetic sensors.

Comment: @glen_geek Good point, I didn't think about those. You don't need *only* analog sensors though; a sensor with an integrated ADC that outputs an 8- to 12-bit value over SPI could still be called a digital sensor. Looking for only "analog" sensors might limit you to analog proportional-output ones, which as I mentioned in the last paragraph, might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [TMAG5273](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/23880) which is a 3d hall effect sensor and has a ±40mT range. You may have to calibrate the sensor if you need better than a few percent accuracy.